# How to do javascript add class active in LI navigation menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can not add class active in LI navigation menu where i click.

When i click on `WHAT WE DO` on `home page` it jump to `what we do page` so i need menu `WHAT WE DO` in `what we do page` to be active.

Here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/smithfoto/Qy7MD/)

### JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {        
  $( "#cssmenu a" ).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var navId = $(this).attr("href");
  var str = '.' + $(this).attr('id');
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(navId).offset().top
    }, 600);

    $(str).show();
    $(this).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass("active");
    $(str).find('li').removeClass("active");
    $(str).closest('ul').find('li').addClass("active");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using same id for multiple elements. Please remove it and use different Ids for different elements.

You can add active class using below jQuery :

```
$(str).find('[href="'+navId+'"]').closest('li').addClass("active");
```

instead of

```
 $(str).closest('ul').find('li').addClass("active");
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qy7MD/6/)

**Note** : as active class has font color white hence it is not visible after adding active class to the li.

Answer (score 2):

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qy7MD/4/)**

You need to find `li` - `a` in `what we do page` to add the class.Change the last line to this,

```
$(str).find('ul li a#'+$(this).attr('id')).parent().addClass("active");
```

Or just

```
$(str).find('a#'+$(this).attr('id')).parent().addClass("active");
```

**Note :** Your markup has Duplicate IDs which is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Element IDs should be unique within the entire document.

Comment: This should not answer of OP's question you should comment it not answer.